# I don't want a "close window" menu item in the task bar context menu for my WPF window

Tags: wpf

I don't want a "close window" menu item in the task bar context menu for my WPF window. My intention is to annoy the user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't see a reason to remove the close command from the menu other than to annoy users you can find information how to modify the system menu of an application in C# using WinAPI calls here:

> http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327

Answer (score 7):

An easier option would be to do this:

```
<Window ShowInTaskbar="False" ... />
```